# Parameter escaping in MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Stored Procedure creation code like this in C# ....

```
string query="CREATE  PROCEDURE `MyProc`(IN `searchText` text, IN `iterationsCount` INT, IN `filterName` char(30))
BEGIN
   DECLARE i  INT;
   SET i = 1;
   SET @sSelectBilling = 'count(distinct t.BillingID) from Billing t';
.....
.....
END"
```

When I try to create this sp via C# using MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); I get error Parameter '@sSelectBilling' must be defined. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself. I need to add  Allow User Variables=true; in the connection string. Following article helped me to figure out
http://markcordell.blogspot.com/2008/12/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 CREATE  PROCEDURE `MyProc` (
      `searchText` text, 
      `iterationsCount` INT, 
       `filterName` char(30) )
 BEGIN
 DECLARE i  INT; 
 DECLARE @sSelectBilling  INT; // define your variable here.
 SET i = 1;
 SET @sSelectBilling = (count(distinct t.BillingID) from Billing t);//use () instead of quotes.
```

Comment: Problem does not seem to be in SP because SP is created fine when I create it manually via MySQL workbench but when I try to create it programmatically, it does not work

Comment: your problem is this `@sSelectBilling` , so how you say is created fine ?

Comment: well, I can not edit the stored procedure.I am copying the stored procedure from one MySQL DB and creating in another DB programmatically. so can't modify the original stored procedure.